# With lme4, is it possible to weight group-level random effects by similarity?

Tags: mixed-model, categorical-data, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, pooling

I'm creating a model with two group-level random effects: `district` (factor) and `age` (factor) and a response, `vodka` (consumption of vodka).

My data looks like this:

```
age Vodka district
 1    50        1
 1    40        2
 1    50        3
 1    60        4
 2    30        1
 2    15        2
 2    30        3
 2    10        4
 3    20        1
 3     5        2
 3    13        3
 3     8        4
 4     8        1
 4     3        2
 4     2        3
 4     6        4
```

I'm realize I can pool my random effects with lme4 with a formula like this:

`Vodka ~ 1 + (1|district) + (1|age)`

But what I'm wondering is, is there a way to pool across the group effects in such a way that if you are in age category 1, more weight is given to group 2, and then less to group 3, and then less to group 4? Likewise, if you are in group 2, more weight is given to groups 1 or 3, and less to group 4. Etc.. If you are in group 3, more weight is given to groups 4 or 2, and less to group 1?

In other words, is it possible to assign a function for the random effects weighting that puts more priority on age groups with a closer factor dummy variable?

A bit more context per @robert.long: The age groups correspond with age ranges. Age `1` is 18-34; Age `2` is 35-45, etc. So my prior belief is that vodka drinkers of similar ages should have more pooling when calculating the group-level random effects than ages that are further apart.

Comment: Please can you explain why you want to apply these weightings and what you hope they will achieve ?

Comment: Sure. @RobertLong. Adding to the post. Have added. Perhaps this is too Bayesian for lme4?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you are looking for is something along the lines:

```
Vodka ~ age + (age | district)
```

i.e., put `age` as a random slope that would say that the correlations in the repeated measurements of your outcome `Vodka` decreasing with increasing time-lag of `age`.

Comment: Thanks, This wouldn't make the a random slope for each district as a product of age? I'm just wondering where the time lag is fit in.

Comment: To see how slopes work with the time lag, check Chapter 3, Section 3.3 in the GitHub app for my Repeated Measurements course:  https://github.com/drizopoulos/Repeated_Measurements